# Source for quote about a slight wrong being a serious matter

Tags: sources-mekorot, derech-eretz-manners, avot-derabbi-natan

I heard someone quote an *Avos D’Rabbi Noson* which said, *“If you have done your fellow man a slight wrong, let it be a serious matter in your eyes… but it you have done him much good, let it be a little thing in your eyes.”* Where in *Avos D’Rabbi Noson* does it says this?

Comment: You have an apparently verbatim quotation, but no citation? Where did you get the quotation from?

Comment: Machsom L'fi quote that was emailed to me from Chofetz Chaim Heritage Foundation.

Comment: Please [edit] as much as you can about your source into your post. Did CCHF not source their quotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

מסכתות קטנות מסכת אבות דרבי נתן נוסחא א פרק מא

רבי יהודה בן תימא אומר הוי עז כנמר וקל כנשר ורץ כצבי וגבור כארי לעשות רצון אביך שבשמים:

הוא היה אומר הוי אוהב את השמים ירא מן השמים חרד ושש מכל המצות. **ואם עשית לחברך רעה קימעא יהא בעיניך הרבה. ואם עשית לחברך טובה הרבה יהא בעיניך מעט**. ואם עשה לך חברך טובה קימעא תהא בעיניך הרבה. אם עשה לך חברך רעה הרבה תהא בעיניך קימעא: